Adjust two Text whit overflow for the first one
I have two Texts in the Row.
The first one can have relatively short or long content, potentially not fitting the row's size. The content of the second text is always constant. If the content of the first Text is short, the second Text should be adjusted to the first one, if the content is long, then the first Text should be elipsible, and the second - pushed to the end and occupied as much space as it can.
This is how UI should look if the content of the first Text is short

This is how UI should look if the content of the first Text is large

I failed to achieve it.
The simplest code that I have
@Composable
fun Example(
    firstText: String,
    secondText: String
) = Row(
    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 16.dp)
) {
    Text(
        text = firstText,
        modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1f)
            .padding(start = 16.dp),
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
        maxLines = 1
    )
    Text(
        text = secondText,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
            .wrapContentWidth()
    )
}

Tried to use ConstraintLayout, but was unable to achieve this requirement as well.

.weight(1f, false) did the trick
